# "1 + 1 should equal 2" or "1 + 1 should equal to 2"; which one is correct?

Tags: prepositions, mathematics

Which of the following is correct?

> 1 + 1 should equal 2.
>
> 1 + 1 should equal to 2.

"equal" or "equal to"?

Comment: Either the first one, or you could say, "1+1 should **be** equal to 2," if you wanted a more verbose version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In maths, it's widely used the word *equals*.
Given the suggestions, *1 + 1 should be equal to 2* is the proper choice. Using *equals* is just *1 + 1 equals 2.*

Now in maths, *should* is not used when we are sure about the result. After working long calculations and having in mind what's the expected result, we introduce *should*.

Comment: _"1 + 1 should be equal to 2"_ is not one of the choices presented.  I hope that the OP accepting this answer does not mean that he thinks that there is anything wrong with saying _"1 + 1 should equal 2"_ - there isn't.

Answer (score 3):

No preposition needed. *"One plus one should equal two".*

However, if *equal* is used as an adjective, *"to"* is needed. *"One plus one should be equal **to** two."*

Comment: @Freewind - although you have accepted the other answer, please read this one also, since it actually answers your question.